# ComponentDidUpdate Inside HOC is not being logged when input value Changes in Container

Tags: reactjs, higher-order-components

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
function logProps(WrappedComponent) {
    return class extends React.Component {
        componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        console.log("inside componentDidUpdate");
       }
        componentDidMount() {
            console.log("insideComponentDidMount");
        }
        render() {
            return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />;
        }
     };
  }
const Container = (props) => {
    const [name, setName] = useState("");
    const handleInputChange = (value) => {
    setName(value);
    };
   return (
      <React.Fragment>
          <input value={name} onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e.target.value)} />
      </React.Fragment>
       );
   };

export default logProps(Container);
```

Here the container component is wrapped inside the logProps HOC. I want to fire the component Did Update function once the input changes. I have used the same HOC as described in the official react docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lots of things to explain here

1. Components are the dummy(stateless) or smart(stateful)
2. Components will render either if props changes or state ()

Let's start from top to bottom respecting hierarchy

1. HOC component renders
   2.`componentDidMount` fires
2. you can type in your child input now
3. you change the value
4. `handleInputChange` is fired
5. `setName` is now called with a new value
6. `Container` component re-renders duo to ()

We don't expect the HOC to update now, cause nothing fancy happened to it till now.
If you want to call `componentDidUpdate` in each character change you must pass props from the `logProps(Component)` parent

something like this

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
function logProps(WrappedComponent) {
    return class extends React.Component {
        componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        console.log("inside componentDidUpdate");
       }
        componentDidMount() {
            console.log("insideComponentDidMount");
        }
        render() {
            return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />;
        }
     };
  }
const Container = ({name, handleInputChange}) => {
   
   return (
      <React.Fragment>
          <input value={name} onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e.target.value)} />
      </React.Fragment>
       );
   };

export default logProps(Container);

// parent.js
const Parent = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  return <LogPropsContainer handleInputChange={setName} name={name} />
}
```

Now you will see the log in every character change [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-brook-89816?file=/src/App.js)

### New Hook version of the logged life cycle

it is convenient to start HOC with `with` keyword

```
const withLogger = (Component) => {
  function HOC(props) {
    useEffect(() => {
      console.log("component did mount", { CDM: props });
      // eslint-disable-next-line
      return () => {
        console.log("component did unmount", { CDUM: props });
      };
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
      console.log("component did update", { CDU: props });
      return () => {
        console.log("component did update rerender", { rerender: props });
      };
    });

    return <Component {...props} />;
  };

  // rename component for better debuging
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
   const name = Component && (Component.displayName || Component.name)
   HOC.displayName = `Logger(${name || 'Anonymous' })`
  }
};
```

Comment: Yes, this i understood but is there any way that i can achive firing the componentDidUpdate when the value in the input box changes

Comment: I updated the answer and add what you need